# Jquery menu and photo gallery not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

My site is under development and seems to be just dandy on all browsers except for IE10.:

For some reason the menu bar and photo gallery, which are both powered by Jquery just dont work.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery Sliding Flexible Menu v2/deploy/js/jquery.sliding-flexible-menu-v2.js"></script>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryEffects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery Sliding Flexible Menu v2/deploy/css/sliding-flexible-menu-v2.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Horizontal
    $("div.menu-horizontal").slidingFlexibleMenuv2({
             buttonSpacing: '1'
    });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox(
                {

                                    transitionIn  : 'elastic',
transitionOut : 'elastic',
easingIn      : 'easeOutBack',
easingOut     : 'easeInBack',
speedIn       : '650',
speedOut      : '650',
changeSpeed   : '650',
                                    padding : '0px',
    });
});
function MM_effectAppearFade(targetElement, duration, from, to, toggle)
{ Spry.Effect.DoFade(targetElement, {duration: duration, from: from, to: to, toggle: toggle});
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="fancyapps-fancyBox-2bb0da9/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></scr ipt>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="fancyapps-fancyBox-2bb0da9/source/jquery.fancybox.css">`
```

Anyone got a clue why this aint working in IE????

Full site here

http://www.heggie5.webspace.virginmedia.com

Cheers

Comment: Yep seems to be a clash with the two scripts as when I remove fancybox script for the other pages  like about, work, play etc the menu works as it should in all browsers but when I go back to index.html the menu isn't working in IE10. dunno what you mean as cannot find the /*IE* comment and where to look for the DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader filter..

Again many thanks for any advice..

Comment: Seemed to be the document mode defaulting to IE7 standards in the browser. I've included <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> in the head just after my title tag and it now opens the document in the latest version of IE.. Sorted. Thanks for all your advice guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Place the fancybox css/images as is (as provided by fancybox download) and place fancybox folder in your application root

   1. Modify the jquery.fancybox-1.3.x.css
      1.Look for the comment /* IE */
      2.Change the src for DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader filter for all classes

Please note, approach 1 is better in my opinion, because if you make change to fancybox css file, updgrades would be difficult.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if I place my fancy box CSS and images in a fancy box folder I'll need to change the source for all the classes. Is that the same for my jquery navigation menu? When I moved my CSS file for the jquery navigation menu and changed the source code to link to it, all my CSS styling vanished for it. Like there was no CSS at all. I did this because when I validated my CSS in w3 schools it came up with an error stating that the sliding flexible menu CSS couldn't be found.